# User feed in DB (possibly DynamoDb)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, database, nosql

I am thinking to use DynamoDB for user feed generation.
I will store UserId (Hash) with PostId (Range). But I need to keep only last 3000 posts in the DB. So I am thinking about having a background task that will clean up the table. 
Is this something reasonable to do ? I'm not sure if this type of range queries will work reasonably fast, since I have about 25mln user records.

Please suggest any other options (except fanout in redis) that might work.

Comment: You might get a better response on [dba.se]. However, be sure to read their [on-topic page](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) prior to posting there to be sure your question is on-topic in it's current form.

Answer (score 5):

Your case is a typical Time Series Data scenario where your records become obsolete as the time goes by. There are two main factors you need to be careful about:

- Make sure your tables have even access patterns

If you put all your posts in a single table and the most recent ones are accessed more frequently, your provisioned throughput will not be used efficiently. 
You should group the most accessed items in a single table so the provisioned throughput can be properly adjusted for the required access. Additionally, make sure you properly define a [Hash Key that will allow even distribution of your data across multiple partitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29501670/dynamodb-when-to-use-what-pk-type).

- The obsolete data is deleted with the most efficient way (effort, performance and cost wise)

The documentation suggests segmenting the data in different tables so you can delete or backup the entire table once the records become obsolete (see more details below).

For example, You could have your tables segmented by month:

```
Posts_April, Posts_May, etc
```

Or by Count, each table containing a max number of records:

```
Posts_1, Posts_2, Posts_3, etc
```

On this case you create a new table once the current one has reached the max number of records, and delete/backup the oldest one when you need to do the cleanup.

I might need some additional information about your use cases to give you better examples on how you can take advantage of this approach.

Find below some references to the operations that you will need to programmatically create and delete tables:

**Create Table**
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_CreateTable.html

**Delete Table**
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteTable.html

Here is the section from the documentation that explains best practices related to Time Series Data:

> **Understand Access Patterns for Time Series Data**
>
> For each table that you create, you specify the throughput
>   requirements. DynamoDB allocates and reserves resources to handle your
>   throughput requirements with sustained low latency. When you design
>   your application and tables, you should consider your application's
>   access pattern to make the most efficient use of your table's
>   resources.
>
> Suppose you design a table to track customer behavior on your site,
>   such as URLs that they click. You might design the table with hash and
>   range type primary key with Customer ID as the hash attribute and
>   date/time as the range attribute. In this application, customer data
>   grows indefinitely over time; however, the applications might show
>   uneven access pattern across all the items in the table where the
>   latest customer data is more relevant and your application might
>   access the latest items more frequently and as time passes these items
>   are less accessed, eventually the older items are rarely accessed. If
>   this is a known access pattern, you could take it into consideration
>   when designing your table schema. Instead of storing all items in a
>   single table, you could use multiple tables to store these items. For
>   example, you could create tables to store monthly or weekly data. For
>   the table storing data from the latest month or week, where data
>   access rate is high, request higher throughput and for tables storing
>   older data, you could dial down the throughput and save on resources.
>
> You can save on resources by storing "hot" items in one table with
>   higher throughput settings, and "cold" items in another table with
>   lower throughput settings. You can remove old items by simply deleting
>   the tables. You can optionally backup these tables to other storage
>   options such as Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3). **Deleting an
>   entire table is significantly more efficient than removing items
>   one-by-one, which essentially doubles the write throughput as you do
>   as many delete operations as put operations.**

Source:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.TimeSeriesDataAccessPatterns

UPDATED ANSWER BASED ON ADDITIONAL COMMENTS:

*"So user ID will be my hash key. What I need is clean up procedure... So obviously based on date separate table approach will not gonna work as data is not filtered by timeframe but by count. In other works I need to have x amount of recent records per each user. And to keep it growing beyond that x amount I need to have clean up process."*

On this case you can pretty much define the `Hash Key` as the `UserId`  and the `PostId` as the `Range Key`.

If each User can have a maximum of 10 Posts then the `Range Key` maximum value would be 10. As you reach the maximum number and the User adds a new post, you start over from 1 automatically replacing the oldest Post from that User (see DynamoDB `PutItem` operation for more details). In the end you are just creating a circular post list per user.

By doing that you are essentially adding the new post AND instantly executing the clean up process with a single write operation.

You might need to create a support table containing the last `PostId` published by each `User`. If you choose to have only a Hash Key defined as the `UserId`, you will be able to lookup the last PostId for a specific user using the `GetItem` operation (which is pretty cheap and fast). The schema for this table could be something as simple as:

`UserId` (`Hash Key`)

`LastPostId` (Number Attribute) - NOT A RANGE KEY

As an example, say that you need to get the last three most recent posts from `UserId` `= ABC`:

**Step1.** Use `GetItem` on `LastPostIds_Table` providing UserId `(Hash Key) = "ABC"`

if `LastPostId = 4` then

**Step2.** Use `BatchGetItem` on `Posts_Table` to get the records with `UserId (Hash Key) = "ABC"` and `PostId (Range Key) = 4, 3 and 2`.

From the returned `PostId`s you will know that 4 is the most recent one and 2 the oldest.

**WARNING**: The use of `BatchGetItem` to return many records [may cause sudden bursts of reading activity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScanGuidelines.html#QueryAndScanGuidelines.BurstsOfActivity). This issue is easily resolved by simply breaking the read operation into several smaller batches.

The `PutItem` can be helpful to implement the Post persistence logic:

> **PutItem**
>   Creates a new item, or replaces an old item with a new item. If an
>   item that has the same primary key as the new item already exists in
>   the specified table, the new item completely replaces the existing
>   item. You can perform a conditional put operation (add a new item if
>   one with the specified primary key doesn't exist), or replace an
>   existing item if it has certain attribute values.

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. To be honest I am not sure whether this will work in my case. What I need is to have the timeline for each user. So user ID will be my hash key. What I need is clean up procedure... So obviously based on date separate table approach  will not gonna work as data is not filtered by timeframe but by count. 
In other works I need to have x amount of recent records per each user. And to keep it growing beyond that x amount I need to have clean up process.

Comment: Thanks for all these details. While it seems that this approach might work, it just has too many moving parts. I am thinking just to find a way to map UserId to list of PostIds.